# passing a custom queryset to a serializer django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have looked at this submission and there is so much clutter in the code I am having a hard time following it: [Pass a custom queryset to serializer in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306875/pass-a-custom-queryset-to-serializer-in-django-rest-framework)

Now currently, I am trying to write a serializer that returns a list of all the cities in my table of venues. There may be many venues in each city, but I only want to return the city name once.

I know I need to create a custom model manager for this to modify the queryset, but I am unsure how to pass it to the serializer. I am rather lost in documentation and example. Do I need to write sql do I not? This is why not having a mentor really is a pain.

what I have so far.

models.py:

```
  class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=imgUnique('venueMedia/venueImages'))
    streetAddress= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Venue, Room

class citySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
```

and my custom model in models.py:

```
class CityListManager(models.Manager):
def get_query_set(self):
    return super(CityListManager, self).get_query_set().filter
```

All of the code is incomplete as I figure this out and put it all together

Answer (score 0):

so looks like I was doing it wrong in the first place here is the working code

```
# queryset for cityListView
def getcityList():

    cityList = Venue.objects.raw("""SELECT  DISTINCT city
                                 FROM Venue""")
    return cityList

class citySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = 'city'
        read_only_fields = 'city'

class cityListViewSet(viewsets.viewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = getcityList()
        serializer = citySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```